# How can I generate HTML code "on the fly" using a list of predefined strings?

Tags: javascript, html, list, web

I am trying to make a website which allows me to define a list of events and then it displays them in simple HTML, sorted into past (ascending order) and future (descending order).

The event list will be a list of tuples, the first element being a code for the date "YYYYMMDD", and the second being an html string, like so:

```
event_list = [
    (20160320, "<b>20th March '16</b> - Event 1<br><br>"),
    (20160506, "<b>6th May '16</b> - Event 2<br><br>"),
    (20150130, "<b>30th January '15</b> - Event 3<br><br>"),
    (20160815, "<b>15th August '16</b> - Event 4<br><br>")
];
```

Then it will generate the date code for today, using some kind of script like this:

```
now = new Date();
var today_code = now.getYear() + now.getMonth() + now.getDate();
today_code = parseInt(today_code);
```

giving a code of `20160420` for today, for example

and then there will be a section in the code that goes like this (please forgive my pseudocode, i dont know javascript or much HTML):

```
<h1>FUTURE:</h1>
sort(event_list, event.date_code, ascending); //sort events by date (smallest first)
for event in event_list:
    if event.date_code >= today_code:
        insert(event.html_text);

<h1>PAST:</h1>
sort(event_list, event.date_code, descending); //sort events by date (largest first)    
for event in event_list:
    if event.date_code < today_code:
        insert(event.html_text);
```

HOPEFULLY, this will generate a web page that looks like this:

## FUTURE:

**6th May '16** - Event 2
**15th August '16** - Event 4

## PAST:

**20th March '16** - Event 1
**30th January '15** - Event 3

I know it is very inefficient running through the list twice, but we aren't talking about 1000s of elements here, it think it should be fine. Sorting twice was the only way I could think of swapping the order of placement, I guess maybe iterating through the list in reverse could work too, if that is possible.

**EDIT:**
My question, reduced is, how can I (a) define a list like this, (b) sort this list, (c) iterate through the list and insert the relevant strings of HTML code.
I could do it in other languages to generate a text file, I just don't really know anything about web stuff or HTML (beyond basic typesetting) or javascript, so I don't know what functions to use or the syntax (or even what to look for)

**EDIT 2:**
If the sorting is too hard or computationally expensive for a webpage, I can make sure that the list is defined already in sorted order, as they will be hardcoded, then I only need to iterate forwards for future events and backwards for past events

Comment: So what exactly is your question? Please review [ask].

Comment: Why are people voting to close this question without making any comments? I tried to be as descriptive of my problem as possible, and give pseudocode for what i am trying to achieve. I have seen much worse questions than this being answered on here, I am not sure why people are objecting to it so much?

Comment: This will be very difficult to maintain.  Hard code it as HTML or use some server-side code to prepare the HTML - don't try to do it with JavaScript.

Comment: What do you mean that it will be difficult to maintain?

Comment: use angular, handlehars, closure+soy, liquid, etc. literally any templating engine.

Comment: This might be of interest to you: https://jsfiddle.net/5ny88ze2/1/

Comment: @guskenny83, at no point have you shown any attempt to solve your problem, nor have you shown [what you've tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com), and your edits don't clarify what your question (singular) is. Instead you've listed a series of requirements as though you're posting a work order that you expect us to fulfill for free.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just put your data in an object

should be something like this

```
var event_list = {};

event_list["20160320"]  = "<b>20th March '16</b> - Event 1<br><br>";
event_list["20160506"]  = "<b>6th May '16</b> - Event 2<br><br>";
event_list["20150130"]  = "<b>30th January '15</b> - Event 3<br><br>";
event_list["20160815"]  = "<b>15th August '16</b> - Event 4<br><br>";

var date_codes = Object.keys(event_list);

var date = new Date();
var  today_code = parseInt(date.getFullYear() + ("0" + (date.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2) + ("0" + date.getDate()).slice(-2));



date_codes.sort();

for(i in date_codes){
   if(parseInt([date_codes[i]]) >= today_code){
      document.getElementById("future_event").innerHTML += event_list[date_codes[i]];
   }
}

date_codes.reverse();

for(i in date_codes){
   if(parseInt([date_codes[i]]) < today_code){
      document.getElementById("past_event").innerHTML += event_list[date_codes[i]];
   }
}
```

see here https://jsfiddle.net/0v0rmzx4/1/

Comment: Thanks, i will try that this afternoon and let you know how it goes!

Comment: (i assume by `pareInt`, you mean `parseInt`?)

Comment: updated the code and added an example :)

Comment: Thanks again, it worked perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

Same as @EricSo, but ameliorated the HTML assignation :

```
var event_list = {};
event_list["20160320"]  = "<b>20th March '16</b> - Event 1<br><br>";
event_list["20160506"]  = "<b>6th May '16</b> - Event 2<br><br>";
event_list["20150130"]  = "<b>30th January '15</b> - Event 3<br><br>";
event_list["20160815"]  = "<b>15th August '16</b> - Event 4<br><br>";

var date_codes = Object.keys(event_list).sort();    
var date = new Date();
var today_code = parseInt(date.getFullYear() + ("0" + (date.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2) + ("0" + date.getDate()).slice(-2));

var futureEvents = "", pastEvents = "";
for(i in date_codes){
    if(parseInt([date_codes[i]]) >= today_code){
        futureEvents = futureEvents + event_list[date_codes[i]];
    } else {
        pastEvents = event_list[date_codes[i]] + pastEvents;
    }
}

document.getElementById("future_event").innerHTML += futureEvents;
document.getElementById("past_event").innerHTML += pastEvents;
```